# Status Code 405 while using google oauth2

Tags: angularjs, django, google-oauth, http-status-code-405

I am using Django with Angular JS to access the Google Drive API. I am following [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app) document from Google. The `FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()` gives me the URL similar to the sample URL mentioned on the page. But the problem is that after `return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)` the browser does not redirect to the `authorize_url` and gives the error as shown in the picture below (`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405`).

[image]

But if I copy pasted the URL, it works fine.

The oauth2 function looks like this.

```
def index(request):

    FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(
        settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON,
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2callback/'
    )
    FLOW.params['access_type'] = 'offline'
    authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
```

And here is the oauth2callback function.

```
def auth_return(request):
    credential = FLOW.step2_exchange(request.GET)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/mycustomurl")
```

I used [this](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) to enable CORS in the Django Server Side. Here is my part of service in Angular that makes the call to oauth2.

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')
    .service('myService', function ($http) {

        this.saveToDrive = function (startYear, endYear, shape) {
            var config = {
                    params: {
                        start: '1999',
                        end: '2002',
                        action: 'download-to-drive'
                    },
                    headers: {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                        'X-Requested-With': null
                    }
            }

            var promise = $http.get('/oauth2/', config)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
            return promise;
        };

    });

})();
```

Please suggest what am I missing here. Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: did you add `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True` or `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST=('127.0.0.1:8000', )` in `settings` ?

Comment: According to doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) -  When DEBUG is True and ALLOWED_HOSTS is empty, the host is validated against ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']. I have DEBUG set as True.

Comment: Right. I deleted that comment. I didn't mean to ask that. Please see the updated one.

Comment: Yes I have `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('127.0.0.1:8000',)` in my settings

Comment: Did you add 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' in `Authorized Javascript Origins` in Google API Console for your web application credentials for OAuth2 ?

Comment: Your code’s causing your browser to send a CORS preflight OPTIONS request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`, which is responding to tell the browser, *Nope*. The 405 response in this case is that Google server saying, We do not accept OPTIONS requests. So the COR preflight fails, and the browser stops right there and never tries your actual request. Anyway, you can’t fix this—your code is trying to do something that `https://accounts.google.com` explicitly doesn’t want you doing. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: @sideshowbarker I found it to be a design issue rather than the code issue. Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it be a minor design issue rather than the code issue. I separated the logic that sends the oauth2 request to the client, and after the oauth2 request, I sent request to internal API with the `params` options. And now it's working fine.